# histogram and density in R by ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, kernel-density

I have a sales data with value from 1 to 3000000. Most counts are in the interval of [1,800]. If I use the following code to plot histogram:

`ggplot(his_data) +
  geom_histogram(aes(x = sales), fill = "grey", color = "black")`

Then the graph looks like:

[image: histogram]

Is it caused by too spreaded bins?  How could I fix such a problem and add density function as well?

Many thanks.

Comment: If all the values are greater than zero (as is likely with sales data) you can use a logarithmic scale `+ scale_x_log10() + geom_density()`

Comment: yes, all values are greater than zero. Is there any example for it? Because there are too many values, R's ggplot looks no meaningful currently.

Comment: I gave you code in my comment...

Comment: Please post a representative sample of your data. It looks like your data is very skewed; you could try options like log-transforming the values to get a better look at it, or removing outliers based on some criteria

Answer (score 0):

Does changing binwidth help?

```
geom_histogram(aes(x = sales),
               binwidth = 100,
               fill = "grey",
               color = "black")
```

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work. my bin range is from 1 to 3,000,000. I guess it's too spreaded?

Comment: you could create two separate plots from 0 to 2000 and then 2000 to whatever high the numbers go or neglect >2000?

Comment: I want them in the same plot. Is there any way to use different wideth of bins in a same graph (ie, one is in 100 but the others are in 100000?

Comment: No idea, not very elegant but maybe plot two different graphs with different bandwidth and then stick them together